# I get NullReferenceException after installing Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads LIte

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]

I get a `NullReferenceException` after installing Google Playservices Ads Lite on the Android project of Xamarin.Forms app. I really don't know where this exception is from and what may have caused it. Anyone who has had a similar problem, please help, I've been stuck on it for long time now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a few problems with GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite, but I have found that using Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads instead seems to work fine. You might try that package instead. It only has a dependency on GooglePlayServices.Basement so you don't end up with a load of other packages as well.